# determining order of $x+1$ given the $x$ has order three

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to expand $(x+1)^n$, then plug $x^3$ in to the expansion of the $(x+1)^n$, keep trying it until I get the order, are there any other ways?
So if $x^3\equiv 1\pmod y$, how would I determine order of $x+1$? 
Can I brute force $x$ and $y$ for the condition then just find $x+1\equiv\pmod y$?

$y$ is prime

Comment: I only understand 'I was trying to expand $(x+1)^n$' so far. Could you clarify a bit on what you're trying to do?

Comment: It depends on the field you are working in, doesn't it?

Comment: Try a few small examples. You should see a pattern.

Comment: "Order"...of what in what algebraic structure??

Answer (score 5):

Clearly $x\neq1$ and hence
$$
x^3 \equiv 1 \Rightarrow x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \tag1$$
Now consider
$(x+1)^6$ and show that
$$
(x+1)^6 - 1 \equiv x\,\left(x+2\right)\,\left(x^2+x+1\right)\,\left(x^2+3\,x+3\right)\tag2$$

and conclude that the order is $6$ by showing no smaller power works.

*Added in response to comments*

Using (1) in (2) we have 
$$(x+1)^6 \equiv 1$$
Hence order of $x+1$ must divide $6$.

1. If $x+1$ has order 1 then $x=0$ which is not possible. *So the order cannot be 1.*
2. if $x+1$ has order 2, then from (1) $x+1 \equiv -x^2$, and hence $(x+1)^2 \equiv x^4$ and $x^4 \not \equiv 1$. *So the order cannot be 2.*
3. if $x+1$ has order 3, then from (1) $x+1 \equiv -x^2$, and hence $(x+1)^3 \equiv -x^6 = -1$. This requires $1 \equiv -1$, which means there are only two elements in the multiplicative group but we know that $1$, $x$ and $x^2$ are distinct since order of $x$ is 3. *So the order cannot be 3.*

**Hence the order has to be $6$**

Comment: so y is being prime is not relevant to the question ? are there any other ways ?

Comment: so x^3-1 =(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0 how did you get 0 from this ?

Comment: +1 and a minor remark that in characteristic two $x+1$ would also be of order three (but $x$ would not be an integer as we would be inside the field of four elements).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please see my edits. Characteristic two implies that $y=2$ (OP implicitly wants $\mod y$) and since $x$ has order 3, there are at least 3 distinct elements.

Comment: @user3308184 You need $y$ to be prime. Given that $x^3\equiv1$ we can conclude $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\equiv 0$. Because $y$ is prime, we can conclude that either $x-1\equiv0$ or $x^2+x+1\equiv 0$. If $y$ were not prime, we can't make this conclusion.  Note saying $x$ has order $3$ is same as saying (a) $x^3\equiv 1$ which is same as $x^3-1 \equiv 0$ and (b) no smaller positive power will give $x^n\equiv 1$. This is why $x\equiv1$ is not possible because order of $1$ is one.

Answer (score 1):

**Key Idea** $\,\ x+1 \equiv (-1)x^{-1}$ has order $= {\rm lcm}({\rm ord}(-1),{\rm ord}(x^{-1})) = {\rm lcm}(2,3) = 6$

Suppose the  modulus $ = p\,$ prime. $\ 0 \equiv x^3\!-1 \equiv (x-1)(x^2\!+x+1).\,$ Then $\,x^2\!+x+1\equiv 0\,$ since $\,x\not\equiv 1\,$ (by $\,x\,$ has order $\,3),\ $ thus we can cancel  $\,x-1\not\equiv 0,\,$ being in a *field* $\ \Bbb Z/p.$

Thus $\ x(x\!+\!1)\equiv -1\ $ so $\, x\!+\!1\equiv -x^{-1}\,$ so $\,x\!+\!1\,$ has order $\,6\,$ by Key Idea $ $ (note $\,-1\,$ has order $\,2,\,$ else it has order $\,1\,$ so $\,-1\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2\equiv 0,\,$ so $\,x\in \Bbb Z/2\,$ has order $\,3,\,$ contradiction). $\ \ $ **QED**

**Note** $\, $ If the modulus  isn't prime then it may fail, e.g. $\,{\rm mod}\ 26\!:\ 3^3\equiv 1\,$ but $\,4^n\not\equiv 1$ for $\,n>0.$